# How can I transform my canvas in PlayN?

Tags: playn

Application screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OzZj.png

Source file: [http://pastie.org/private/rcgm6o7qso8y0vz8nfjn0w](http://pastie.org/private/rcgm6o7qso8y0vz8nfjn0w#68-72)

My application draws curves and I would like to be able to zoom in and out. When I apply a scale and translate transformation, the `mapCanvasImage.canvas().gfx.transform` changes accordingly, but nothing changes on the screen.

[image]

I used to have a different render approach ([source code](http://pastie.org/private/dbrokcx9bnpohyvcf4lq#83-87)) in which the transformation *did* work, but there I could not get the layer to clear after each paint (results from previous paint iterations were still visible).

Perhaps (or likely) I am doing something fundamentally wrong. :) Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The Canvas offers nice high-level functions to draw Bézier curves, but is apparently flawed. My current plan is to abandon the Canvas and write my own code to convert Bézier curves to line segments. This is really easy and gives the added benefit of using less CPU power, since the Canvas is not hardware accelerated.